# execute php script without waiting response in yii2 framework

Tags: php, yii

i'm using yii framework and i want to run php script in a page such as index.php .
but I do not want to waiting for response. (such as send sms that perhaps operator do not respond and it causes stop my script).

i'm using yii2 framework and have some actions in controllers and commands.

what the best issue ???? (except send ajax method)

Comment: i searched in web and no found my best solution.

Comment: If you exclude AJAX as a possible solution, why did you tag this question as AJAX?

Comment: thanks i am begginer in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I see you do not want to wait for your sms code to return an answer. What you can do is to have a "messages" table (choose the name fits your needs) and then configure a cronjob which reads every x minutes from it and executes the controller/action which check if there are pending items on "messages" and send them.

Comment: min time for cronjob is 1min. and i want to process sms request force. but no waiting for sms response.

Answer (score 0):

give it a check to this https://github.com/reactphp/promise. it implements promises on php. i have not tried though